# Return 1st from 1, 2nd from 2, ..., 11th from 11, 

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a Objective-c function to return a `NSString *` from a `NSUInteger`, i.e.:

- 1 -> 1st
- 2 -> 2nd
- ...
- 10 -> 10th
- 21 -> 21st
- ...
- 31 -> 31st

for the range from 1 to 31. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)stringFromInt:(int)num {
    NSString stringAddition;
    if (num%100 >= 11 && num%100 <= 13) {
        stringAddition = @"th";
    }
    else {
        switch (num % 10) {
            case 1: stringAddition = @"st"; break;
            case 2: stringAddition = @"nd"; break;
            case 3: stringAddition = @"rd"; break;
            default: stringAddition = @"th"; break;
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@", num, stringAddition];
}
```

**EDIT**:
Fixed the 11, 12, 13 issue.

Comment: You call returning "11st" working? "12nd"? "13rd"? "31st" is good, but "11st" is pure breakage. Those special cases probably deserve their own `if()` statement, if you're really going to cover all your bases. Also I'd much rather this method be called maybe "ordinalFromInt", rather than "stringFromInt"--that name doesn't tell me we're adding anything, I'd expect it to be shorthand for `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num]`.

Comment: You need just a bit more, just above the return: `if(num >= 11 && num <= 13) stringAddition = @"th";`.

Comment: Design-wise, code like this would probably fit best in an NSNumberFormatter subclass.

Comment: The above code will break for 113, 213, 1013 etc. won't it?  I suggest making the check if (num%100 >=11 && num%100 <= 13)